# Add to cart button/URL

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, url, addtocart, phtml

I am using Magento 1.7.

In the page `myUrl/customer/account`, I created a table that shows the amount of each product that was ordered in the last orders. The first column contains the product name, the last column contains a link for buying the product again, and the columns in the middle contain the amount of product ordered for each one of the last orders.

[image]

In `recent.phtml`, under `app/design/frontend/default/CUSTOM_THEME/template/sales/order`, I obtained the names of the products as follows (snippet of the code):

```
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders();
    foreach ($_orders as $_order) 
    {
            $items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $name = $item->getName();
                (...)
            }
    }
?>
```

And I obtained the add to cart URL as follows:

```
<?php
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('name',$name);    
    $addToCartURL = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);
?>
```

But this URL is not adding the product to the cart, it only redirects to the product page.

I found that in the product page the add to cart button that is actually working, has this code:

```
<button type="button" title="Agregar al carrito;" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
        <span>Agregar al carrito;</span>
</button>
```

I am also able to obtain the simple products instead of the configurable ones, in case this is needed.

My question is, how can I insert a button/URL in the last column of my table so that when I click on it the product gets added to the cart. Any help is much appreciated.